# jquery - check for part of a url

Tags: jquery, html, url, if-statement

I'm using jquery, and I need to check the URL to see if the user is looking at tagged/categorized content.

I need to check the URL to do so. Before, I was doing something like this to check to see what page the user was on...

```
var loc = window.location; 
var pageOne = 'http://design.optimus.com/projects';
if(loc == pageOne) { 
//do stuff
}
```

But these URLs never changed, so it was easy for me to check if they were on a single URL or not.

However, the new urls are going to have different endings depending on the tag the user searches for. For example,

```
http://optidesign.squarespace.com/projects/tag/design
http://optidesign.squarespace.com/projects/tag/production
http://optidesign.squarespace.com/projects/tag/animation
```

So I want to use sort of the same method as the first part, but I just want to check for the beginning of the URL:

```
http://optidesign.squarespace.com/projects/tag/
```

How do i go about doing this?

Comment: You want to check for the word that follows the `tag` 'directory'?

Comment: Yes. Well, if there is a /tag/ anywhere in the URL, then perform a function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) method can be used for this purpose:

```
if (location.href.indexOf('http://optidesign.squarespace.com/projects/tag/') === 0) {
    // Well...
}
```

I can imagine that you test the pages on `localhost`, or at a different protocol. The following solution might be more useful:

```
if (location.pathname.indexOf('/projects/tag/') === 0) {
    // Well...
}
```

Comment: Is the === 0 the same as returning true or false?

Comment: @patricko `=== 0` is an [identity operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use). It returns `true` when the value and type at both sides are equal, `false` otherwise.

Comment: Also, if it's of any help to you, I have nice little [plugin](http://spyk3lc.blogspot.com/2012/03/jquery-myurl-extension-how-to-get-that.html) that makes any and all calls to ur sites url **EASY**. See working [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/2ZuTe/).  Examples of how to use it are on my [blog](http://spyk3lc.blogspot.com/2012/03/jquery-myurl-extension-how-to-get-that.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the page contents, you could simply add a variable to pass into your script stating which page you are on.

Assuming the URL is the only data you have to go off, you can use the [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to see if that part of the URL is present or not.

```
var loc = window.location.toString(); 
var pageOne = 'http://design.optimus.com/projects/tag/';
if(loc.indexOf(pageOne) >= 0) { 
//do stuff
}
```

In order to be future-proof in case you change domain or switch to HTTPS, you could alternatively use the following:

```
var loc = window.location.pathname; 
var pageOne = '/projects/tag/';
if(loc.indexOf(pageOne) >= 0) { 
//do stuff
}
```

I have put an example on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gEtG2/1/) you can play with.

Comment: All i have access to is the URL.

that function doesn't seem to be working for me...

Comment: @patricko - you're correct, the window.location needed a toString(). I've update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know what page the user is on, assuming that's the 'directory' following the `tag`, then I'd suggest:

```
if (url.indexOf('tag')) {
    var temp = url.split('/tag/')[1];
    var curPage = temp.substring(0,temp.indexOf('/'));
    return curPage;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/wMwTE/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `window.location.pathname` instead, cause the hostname (stackoverflow.com for example) is always the same.
So, window.location.pathname will give you the rest of the URL. In this example, will give you:
**"/questions/9706497/jquery-check-for-part-of-a-url"**

Now, if you want to check the first two segments, you can split the string:

```
window.location.pathname.split("/");
```

That will give you:

```
["", "questions", "9706497", "jquery-check-for-part-of-a-url"]
```

And now check the index you need, for example:

```
parts = window.location.pathname.split("/");
if (parts[1] == "projects") {
    alert("Projects!!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To just check if 'tag' is present:

```
if (window.location.match(/tag/)!==null) {
    //do something
}
```

To remove the last part of any URL:

```
var url = window.location.split('/');
    url.pop();
    url = url.join().replace(/,/g, '/')+'/';
```